# Google Cloud Vision API not recognizing Dot Matrix Printed characters

Tags: google-cloud-vision

Google Vision API does not recognize characters printed by Dot Matrix printer. Please see one screenshot where Vision API has not selected block with DMP printing. Need to capture this information.

Also, how to put together an information based on the categorization placed on the object image submitted to the API.
Thanks,
Raman

[image]